# Prettier and ESLint jQuery spacing

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, eslint, prettier

I have code that when formatted with Prettier ESLint gives me an error

ORIGINAL:

```
  $(document).trigger('HideDropDown').trigger('UpdateDropDowns');
```

FIXED with Prettier

```
  $(document)
    .trigger('HideDropDown')
    .trigger('UpdateDropDowns');
```

ESLINT complains that I need extra spaces as such:

```
  $(document)
      .trigger('HideDropDown')
      .trigger('UpdateDropDowns');
```

Is this something that needs to be adjusted through Prettier or ESLint? I do prefer only two spaces rather than 4 but I am not sure how to adjust it so that ESLint doesn't complain about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I figured out that the following setting would allow ESLint and Prettier work together well:

```
"MemberExpression": 1 // default is 2
```

Comment: I wonder why Google decided to use 2 as default instead of 1. Maybe readability?